# what does it mean by putting two variable in a for-in loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems](https://www.amazon.ca/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Learn-TensorFlow/dp/1491962291). In an example, I see this syntax in for loop.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

I printed out the train_index and test_index, they are array of indices.
What does this for loop mean? The train_index and test_index have different number of elements, how does iteration work? 
Is this code equivalent to the below?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
train_index, test_index = split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

Comment: I guess `split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"])` returns a two tuple value, and doing `train_index, test_index` in the for loop unpacks the two values into the two variables respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple case of 2 variables in a for loop:

```
In [173]: for a,b in [[0,1],[10,12]]:
     ...:     print(a,b)
     ...:     
0 1
10 12
```

If works for the same reason that:

```
In [174]: a,b = [10,12]
```

The iteration returns some sort of tuple or list, and the `a,b in ...` unpacks the 2 values into the the matching number of variables.

```
for i, v in enumerate(['a','b','c']):
    print(i,v)
```

is another common use of unpacking in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The below codes are cited from sklearn's manual.[enter link description here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits(X, y)
5
print(sss)
StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, random_state=0, ...)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

TRAIN: [5 2 3] TEST: [4 1 0]
TRAIN: [5 1 4] TEST: [0 2 3]
TRAIN: [5 0 2] TEST: [4 3 1]
TRAIN: [4 1 0] TEST: [2 3 5]
TRAIN: [0 5 1] TEST: [3 4 2]
```

For loop runs n_splits times.