# What does this 'for m,n in matches'?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I need to know specifically what the line `for m, n in matches` does to be able to implement it in C. `matches` is a matrix, but what values does `m` and `n` take and how do they move?

This is python code...

```
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
```

NOTE In C++ `matches` is a `std::vector<DMatch>` and is an OpenCV program.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the complete type of `matches` in the C++ version? In Python, `for m,n in matches` suggests that `matches` is an iterable where each element is a tuple or list holding a pair of values that you are reading as `m` and `n` in the loop. So then in the C++ version, is `matches` of type `vector<pair<...>>`, `vector<vector<...>>`, or something else?

Comment: SO question for [Multiple Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5182573/2823755).

Comment: I just illustrated this in https://stackoverflow.com/q/44771384

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using the knnMatcher and following the tutorial at http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

`m` and `n` are `DMatch` objects. Two objects are returned because `k=2` at

`matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)`.

If you increase the value of `k` to 3, you will need

`for m,n,p in matches:`

to capture the results.

The CPP equivalent of knnmatch returns a vector of vectors of DMatch as is shown [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#void%20DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch(const%20Mat&%20queryDescriptors,%20const%20Mat&%20trainDescriptors,%20vector%3Cvector%3CDMatch%3E%20%3E&%20matches,%20int%20k,%20const%20Mat&%20mask,%20bool%20compactResult)%20const)

In fact, if you print out `m.queryIdx, m.trainIdx,  n.queryIdx, n.trainIdx` you will see a pattern like `264 323 264 490`indicating that the same index in the query image is matched against other indices in the training image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
 =)

Answer (score 0):

`m` and `n` are the values present at each iteration through `matches`. "How they move" depends on the type of `matches` and what kind of iteration it provides. If it's a list of tuples, then they will each move straight down the list, element by element.